# Avoid filter:brightness property to apply on border color

Tags: html, css

I have following div. I applied color `rgb(134,130,7)` to border. I want its lighter version to be applied on background. So I tried

```
filter: brightness(150%);
```

but this property also lights the `border-color`. Any solution?

```css
.color-filter {
  background: rgb(134, 130, 7);
  filter: brightness(150%);
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(134, 130, 7);
}
```

```html
<div class="color-filter">
  Hi ! How you doiing!!
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the expected result screenshot.
Or you can add opacity in rbg component?
Do you want bg to be light, so that it can be differentiate with border?
background: rgb(134, 130, 7, 0.7);

Comment: @Mangesh yup background color should be ligher version of border color

Comment: `filter` is applied to the whole element, including `:before` and `:after`. Are you able to edit the HTML? If yes, you could add a parent-div and set the `border` on that: https://jsfiddle.net/gdetmkfb/